# Set API Data(JSON) Dynamically in Database views.py in Django using model when NUmber of columns of each tables are different

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

[some of my static code i want to do did dynamically for all models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypxcf.png)Set API Data(JSON)  Dynamically in Database  views.py in Django using model when NUmber of columns of each tables are different.
I mean i am sending data from desktop software to web using api...
in web I am getting that json data using request ,
Now i have alot of model classes that have different number of columns ,
i have tried alot of things but in knownledge nothing seem to be working ...

I can add the data statically but would take alot of time to write the code,
i  have list of table_names so, Is there any way that code will automatically read the json data.
Fetch Rows  and columns from it and than add the numbers of rows to database . and vice versa